# How to visualize three separate arrays representing hue, saturation, and value in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, data-visualization, hsv

Is it possible to take three separate arrays representing hue, saturation, and value and plot them in python? I have two sets of data, one which I want to represent with hue and saturation, and another which I want to represent with value.

I think this may be a similar output to imshow (data1) with the colormap set to something where hue and saturation vary with data2. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imshow` expects RGB(A) values: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=imshow#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow

but the `color` module has a function to translate HSV to RGB: http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html?highlight=hsv#matplotlib.colors.hsv_to_rgb

so you'll want to make a MxNx3 array of your HSV data translated into RGB, and then `imshow` that.

But hue doesn't have all the information needed to make an RGB value -- all three HSV values will affect all three RGB values.